# What is the JPype version we should use for JDK11?

Tags: java, aws-lambda, java-11, aws-lambda-layers, jpype

When I am trying to create a object using Jpype,

```
my_class = jpype.JClass("java.lang.Class").forName('com.java.example.SampleJavaClass')
```

I am getting `SampleJavaClass has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0",` I know that this is due to using different JDK versions, however I am using JDK11 to build the jar and Python 3.7. I can't build my jar using JDK8. So, Is there any way to resolve this?

Python code is in aws lambda, java jar in aws lambda layer.
Thanks in advance.